# Laravel API returning different model user

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have 2 models `Admin` and `User` i am able to grant `access_token` for both models by modifying `UserRepository` and `PasswordGrant` by referring https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161

every thing is fine in granting `access_token` but when request the user details
`http://localhost:8000/api/user` i'm getting the user details for `User` model.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "App User",
    "email": "appuser@gmail.com",
    "created_at": "2017-07-04 10:01:52",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-04 10:01:52"
}

//but i should be getting the user details of `admin` model
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "created_at": "2017-07-04 10:01:52",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-04 10:01:52"
}
```

I guess when requesting the `user` is referring to `User` model not the`Admin` model

my `auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

i'm just returning the user in my `routes/api.php` route

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user(); 
});
```

looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: How do you access the user data from the request? Did you consider that you are doing a request  in the web middleware context where you user session is still valid?

Comment: @Frank Provost  thank you for your time really appreciate it, i'm working on `api` it is not a website just `api` for front end applications

Comment: so can you provide the code sample of where you access the relevant user and where it returns the wrong one?

Comment: @Frank Provost, i have up dated my post

Comment: ah i see - i think that $request->user() will give you the user of the default guard which is web. You sould change the guard or try "Auth::guard('api')->user();" to access to user - don't forget to add "use Auth;" at the beginning of your file

Comment: i'm getting this error `1/1) ErrorException
The use statement with non-compound name 'Auth' has no effect` line 3 is `use Auth;`

Comment: instead of putting use Auth at the beginning you can use it directly with \Auth::guard('api')->user()

Comment: @Frank Provost hey thank you it worked, i really appreciate your time

Comment: if you really want an api only you can change the default guard to api - then all helpers will use this one. I've added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default laravel uses the web guard. You can use the api guard like

```
\Auth::guard('api')->user()
```

To access the user